# Find highly composite number using Python 3

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, mathematics

A highly composite number (HCN) is a positive integer with more divisors than any smaller positive integer ha according to Wikipedia. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JM2oImb9Qg) is a YouTube video about it.

```
def get_divisors(number_range):
  divisor_list = []
  divisor_list2 = []
  for number in range(1,number_range+1):
    for e in range(1,number_range+1):
      if number % e == 0:
        divisor_list2.append(e)
    divisor_list.append(divisor_list2)
    divisor_list2 = []
  return divisor_list

def get_highly_composite_number(number_range):
  divisor_list = get_divisors(number_range)
  highly_composite_number_list = []
  number_of_divisor_list = []
  number_of_divisor_list2 = []
  number_of_divisor_list3 = []
  tracker = 0
  for e in divisor_list:
    number_of_divisor_list.append(len(e))
    number_of_divisor_list2.append(max(number_of_divisor_list))
  for e in number_of_divisor_list2:
    number_of_divisor_list3.append(e)
    if number_of_divisor_list3[tracker] == max(number_of_divisor_list3) and number_of_divisor_list3.count(number_of_divisor_list3[tracker]) == 1:
      highly_composite_number_list.append(tracker+1)
      tracker += 1
    else:
      tracker += 1
  return highly_composite_number_list
```

I know the naming is horrible, but I did not know any better ways. Also, I know this can probably be condensed, but I did not want to touch it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, the naming is not good and the code can be condensed and optimized.

- You don't need to keep all the lists, you just need the count
- You can split `get_divisors` so you have another function to get the divisors of a single number
- You can use a dictionary to store the divisor count of the numbers.

This would already take care of the variable names:

```
def get_divisors_count(number):
  divisors = []
  for divisor in range(1, number + 1):
    if (number % divisor) == 0:
      divisors.append(divisor)
  return len(divisors)

def get_divisors_range(number_range):
  divisor_count = {}
  for number in range(1, number_range):
    divisor_count[number] = get_divisors_count(number)
  return divisor_count

def get_highly_composite_number(number_range):
  divisor_list = get_divisors_range(number_range)
  highly_composite_number_list = []
  for i in range(number_range - 1, 0, -1):
    found = False
    for j in range(1, i):
      if (divisor_list[j] >= divisor_list[i]):
        found = True
        break
    if (not found):
      #If you want the list sorted from low to high
      #change this to highly_composite_number_list.insert(0, i)
      highly_composite_number_list.append(i)
  return highly_composite_number_list
```

- This could also be optimized a bit using a lookup for numbers of which you already computed the divisors. For examples, `4` is a divisor of `8`, but when you check `8`, you can lookup the divisors of `4` and use that.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing I spotted when I saw your code was the indentation. In python, you should use **4 spaces** per indentation level. More, you should have 2 new lines between your methods and keep your lines no longer than 120 characters (in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - which is the official python style-guide, the limit is of 79 characters but I like to stick with InteliJ's recommendation).

More, based on [ChatterOne's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/157031/61966) I'd rewrite his first two functions as follows:

```
def get_divisors_count(number):
    """What does this function do?"""
    return len([divisor for divisor in range(1, number + 1) if (number % divisor) == 0])


def get_divisors_range(number_range):
    """What does this function do?"""
    return {number: get_divisors_count(number) for number in range(1, number_range)}
```

In the first function I've used list comprehension and in the second one dictionary comprehension. You can read more about them (and their advantages) [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

Last but not least, you should definitely add [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id33) to your functions to describe their functionality.

Another thing you might do is adding the [`if __name__ == '__main__'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158605/6165050) guard.

Comment: Why not `sum(1 for divisor in range(1, number + 1) if (number % divisor) == 0)`?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I thought of this too, but if you'll benchmark the two, (yours and mine), you'll get a _slightly_ better time for list comprehension. See [here](https://repl.it/GIbq).

Comment: Interestingly enough, timings tend to be the same if you setup the test to look like the actual computation: https://repl.it/GIbq/1